# Reading and Averaging Multiple CSV files

Tags: arrays, excel, csv

I have a large directory of csv files(UV-Vis spectra many rows with two columns corresponding to wavelength and some measurement), seperated by day, then unique sample identifier, and then scan number. I'm trying to csvread all the scans for one sample on one day and average the measurement value and leave the wavelength the same, and plot the averages in a 2d line plot.

I've been using the following code to read the csv's into a cell array based on another post on this site:

```
d=dir('folder\*.csv');
for i=1:length(d)
m{i}=csvread(d(i).name)
end
```

However I have to go in an convert each cell of the array back into a matrix and trim to the wavelength range im interested in using the cell2mat function. Because when I try to do it iteratively with a for loop it creates another cell array.

Is there an easier way to Average and Trim my cell arrays?

Comment: I'm confused by `m{i}=csvread(d(i).name)`... aren't the curly brackets just for vb.net? Can anyone tell how `{}` work in vba?